# Selenium, AutoIt, Sikuli experience compare?

Tags: selenium, autoit, sikuli

I am job searching and am seeing a lot of Selenium requirements in job descriptions lately.  I know that Selenium is an automation tool for web testing but what I don't know is how it compares to using AutoIt and Sikuli.  I am very familiar with AutoIt and Sikuli tools but not familiar with Selenium as far as enterprise use.  I could simply download Selenium and fool around with it but as far as professional experience, I have none.

So my question to automation professionals out there is if I have a good deal of experience in AutoIt and Sikuli, would I be a good fit for a position that deals solely with Selenium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have experience only with AutoIt and Selenium .
What I can say about AutoIt -> script written on it  are suitable for WIN platform only.
Imagine the situation when you need to run you test (that covers a piece of functionality on a web page) on 2 notes: win note and macBook. 
For Win your script be working OK , for Mac it will fail. 
OR, a little bit modified: if you need run your script simultaneously on several machines and/or in several browsers. Selenium will fit OK  for this. 
But for another side: such case like attachment a file on a webPage or any other kinda of attachment - will not work with pure Selenium. AutoIt will handle it nice.

So it was 2 little casees in particular.
In overall, selenium  is used for functional UI  automation of web application(-s) .  And if you have experience of scripting you will be able to adjust your skills.

My recommendation to you - start recording script with SElenium IDE , then export these recorded scripts in testNg , and then try to understand their structure.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has fairly extensive experience with Sikuli and Selenium (but none at all with Autolt), I would say that Sikuli skills are not very transferable to Selenium. The theory side--the logic and algorithmic thinking you'd use to problem solve would be much the same, but the technique of execution are so very different between the two, that if I were doing the hiring, I wouldn't hire a person with no experience in Selenium but vast experience in Sikuli, if there were any reasonable Selemium-experienced people to choose from.

I imagine, though, that if you could demonstrate proficiency, or create and show your own projects that use an array of Selenium skills, that could go a long way to smoothing reservations a hiring company might have...

Take that for what it's worth, esp since I have no experience with Autolt.

Answer (score 0):

**Selenium** is used for Web-Automation or Web Applications or website related automation.

**Autoit** can only be used for Windows GUI Automation or Windows based applications. No Image Recognition purely on elements based usage.

**Sikuli** on the other hand, can be used for automating both i.e. Desktop Apps and Web-Apps. It basically finds the match of the given Image in the screen by using Image Recognition and then you can perform tasks on that like click, double click, input text etc.